# A term that can be used to group towns and provinces together

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I've been given some names of towns and provinces for a tourism web-site. Is there a hypernym that could categorize both of them together? I've been thinking of the word "locality" but I'm not sure if that's suitable.

Comment: Both towns and provinces are places, but this may be too general a name for your purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need this word for the website, e.g. as the menu item that leads to the list of towns and provinces, I'm going to go ahead and answer what Gorpik suggested in a comment: ***places***. Your own suggestion of ***localities*** could also work. I'd lean slightly toward the plurals, but if you don't want to — for example if the rest of the menu items are not plural — you could also use the singular forms ***place*** or ***locality***.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatives include: Region , Area, Valley, Greater:

Examples:  Philadelphia Area, Bay Area, Delaware Valley, Greater London.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to emphasize the people in those towns and provinces, you could use the term *community* or *communities*.

[*Community*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/community) is not limited by geographic size:

> 1.
>   a social group of any size whose members reside in a specific locality, share government, and often have a common cultural and historical heritage.
>
> 2.
>   a locality inhabited by such a group.

Answer (score 1):

[Conurbation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conurbation) might fit into your mix for some of the more built up areas. Careful though, the word might either ooze sophistication, or send irritated potential customers haring off after a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a tourism web site, I think the commonly used term is "destinations". That's pretty vague, I assume deliberately so, and can include anything from a nation to a hotel to an amusement park.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I would use [megapolis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megalopolis_%28city_type%29). At least that is what I remember we were using back in my Geography classes.

Comment: I think maybe you need to go look up the definition of *hypernym*.

Comment: @Marthaª - A linguistic term for a word whose meaning includes the meanings of other words; the opposite of hyponym. I do not  get what you mean here.

Comment: She means that a megalopolis is a lot of cities mushed together next to each other, a -collection- of cities. A hypernym includes the idea, not the items. A dog is a kind of mammal ('mammal' is the hypernym), a collection of dogs doesn't make a mammal.

Comment: A *province* is just a **region** (usually administrative), but it doesn't necessarily include many if any urban centres, let alone *cities*. A *megapolis* is a large conurbation, usually including at least one city. If there's a hypernym for *provinces* and *towns* (which I doubt), *megapolis* certainly isn't it.